# Using External_ID__c no records are being loaded in Contacts in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, mule

After copying an example Bulk API upsert in Mule, I had to add External_ID to Contacts in Salesforce as a number and External ID. I am sending External_ID, FirstName, and LastName. I get no errors in Mule console but I do get an id as if it tries. I also get recordsProcessed 0 and recordFailures 0.

I don't know where to go next. Was there something I needed to turn on in my free Salesforce account? What can I check on the Mule side of things. A colleague did the same thing and his worked. I'm using his CSV files for import.

```
INFO  2018-04-24 13:24:33,797 [[sys-nf-sfdc-bulk].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: /Users/ciwise/AnypointStudio/workspace-dlw/sys-nf-sfdc-bulk/src/main/resources/source2.csv
WARN  2018-04-24 13:24:34,972 [[sys-nf-sfdc-bulk].test-pickup-load.stage1.02] org.mule.modules.salesforce.config.AbstractConfig: API version 37.0 is lower than the recommended 41.0 version
INFO  2018-04-24 13:24:39,240 [[sys-nf-sfdc-bulk].test-pickup-load.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: [BatchInfo  id='7516A000004DyX2QAK'
 jobId='7506A0000051OpjQAE'
 state='Queued'
 stateMessage='null'
 createdDate='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1524590679000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=17,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=24,DAY_OF_YEAR=114,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=24,SECOND=39,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]'
 systemModstamp='java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1524590679000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2018,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=17,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=24,DAY_OF_YEAR=114,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=24,SECOND=39,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=0]'
 numberRecordsProcessed='0'
 numberRecordsFailed='0'
 totalProcessingTime='0'
 apiActiveProcessingTime='0'
 apexProcessingTime='0'
]
```

Suggestions? Troubleshooting thoughts? How can I further debug?

David

Comment: I debugged Mule. I drop the CSV file and the polling picks it up. The data stream is converted to a Java collection with the right stuff for Salesforce. I step to Salesforce component and an asychronous batch is instantiated and next step to Logger shows a paragraph in the console. I'll add the paragraph to the original question now.

Answer (score 0):

The Bulk API is asynchronous and the message I saw in the console in Anypoint Studio was acceptable. I found the Bulk Data Load listing and my Contacts were inserted successfully.